# Javascript , Html5 Canvas after rendering once, update it

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

im trying to create a loading bar with the html CANVAS tag.

I can create the canvas and the bars(rectangles) and all works but the only thing I cant seem to figure out is how to update the bars with a green colour.

I have tried using a button with a 'onclick' that calls the function

```
function drawbars(ctx){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
}
```

but this does nothing.

I then thought to clear the canvas each time a bar has to be drawn, and then I could not find a way to draw the right amount of bars for each percentage that was loaded.

This is what I have now ...

-a function that draw a canvas with 100 rectangles like
this works fine.

```
for (var n = 0; n < 100; n++){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(x+margin,0,5,25);
}
```

-and this I thought would update each bar(rectangle) in the canvas with a diffrent colour.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
```

the question remain : how do you create a canvas with 100 bars and then fill them up by a % percentage from left to right.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About Canvas and drawings on Canvas...**

When any existing drawing  on the canvas needs to change (recolor, resize move, erase, etc), the standard method is to completely erase the canvas and redraw the canvas with the elements in their new sizes and positions (or not redraw the elements if they are erased).

That's because canvas does not "remember" where it drew any individual element and therefore cannot individually move or erase any element.

It's up to you to "remember" enough information about an element to redraw it after the canvas has been erased.

So use something like this to erase/redraw your progress guage: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/XM5ZH/

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var margin=2;
var cellWidth=3;
var cellHeight=5;
var progress=1;

animate();

function drawProgress(completeColor,incompleteColor,completeCount){

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    for (var n = 1; n < completeCount; n++){
        ctx.fillStyle = completeColor;
        ctx.fillRect(n*cellWidth+margin,50,cellWidth,cellHeight);
    }    

    for (var n = completeCount; n < 100; n++){
        ctx.fillStyle = incompleteColor;
        ctx.fillRect(n*cellWidth+margin,50,cellWidth,cellHeight);
    }    

}

function animate(){

    if(progress<100){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }

    drawProgress("green","red",progress);

    progress++;

}
```